# Simple HTML DOM - replace all occurrences of a certain word - without affecting attributes

Tags: php, regex, simple-html-dom

I was wondering: how would I change all occurrences of a certain word in a HTML, but only outside of tags?

Example:
 Lets say I want to replace all occurrences of `myWordToReplace` with `<a href="#">myWordToReplace</a>`

So this html

```
<p data-something="myWordToReplace"> myWordToReplace andSomeOtherText</p>
```

should yield

```
<p data-something="myWordToReplace"> <a href="#">myWordToReplace</a> andSomeOtherText</p>
```

I was trying to achieve this with regex, but it's also a mess - I thought perhaps a DOM parser would do the trick? 
Any help appreciated?

**EDIT:** @Muhammet's answer will do the trick if all your text is wrapped in some tags - but if parts of your text are without a tag, that text will not be replaced of course. I'm now trying to achieve this too.

Example: if I want to change `myWord` to `someOtherWord`:

```
Nam myWord pharetra <strong>auctor myWord</strong>
```

Should yield

```
Nam someOtherWord pharetra <strong>auctor someOtherWord </strong>
```

but now it only changes the second word - the one inside strong tags.

Comment: That is not a trivial thing. I would recommend against a pure regex approach here, since that would be a _huge_ effort. You would need a state machine for this, and a pretty complex one.... Take a look at a DOM parser instead, iterate over the elements and _then_ use a regex to replace patterns inside each elements content.

Comment: It's exactly what I was thinking of - but didn't know how to approach so I asked this question. you said to take a look at DOM parser instead? This IS a DOM parser I'm talking about here ...?

Comment: No, a pure regex approach would be a string parser, since you input a string, replace words inside it and output a string. A DOM parser is something else, a software component that actually knows about the structure of HTML markup. It parses your input into a DOM tree (a tree of elements) which you can iterate over: This has the advantage that you have qualiffied objects where you can easily tell apart properties and content. Something like this: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: can you post the HTML you need to parse or a bigger sample?

Comment: @trainoasis: Can you clarify the problem you are having? You say outside of tags, but it's not clear with your example. The text is inside p tag.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds a bit weird sorry. In example you can see the real meaning: replacing words inside tags, but outside each tag name (where tags have attributes etc). Changed title of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
$html = file_get_html($file_url);
$content = $html->find('text');

foreach($content as $line) {
    if(strpos($line->innertext, 'myWordToReplace') !== false) {
        $line->innertext = str_replace('myWordToReplace','<a href="#">myWordToReplace</a>', $line->innertext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, this is _exactly_ what I suggested in the comments above.

Comment: So you are going line by line? Why don't you use the method "find" to actually look for what you need?

Comment: @SpongePablo Because OP might want to replace all occurences and not just _p_

Comment: maybe you need change `$line->innertext = '<a href="#">myWordToReplace</a>';` to `str_replace`, if you find by strpos ?

Comment: it is OP problem. You code finds `<p> this is  myWordToReplace </p>` but i'm not sure that correcty changes. Read his 2nd sentence

Comment: This seems to work-I ll have to edit a bit to change only my word and not the whole innertext as you are doing - but otherwise this seems ok. Will try to improve and get back to you. See my edited question also (other text inside should stay intact :) )

Comment: @splash58 Yeah I see now what you mean, see the update.

Comment: Managed to get it working using $line->innertext = str_replace('myWord', '<span class="highlighted">myWord</span>', $line->innertext);

Comment: @Muhammet you have it correct, but str_replace should assign a value to $line->innertext :) Thanks for your time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82673/discussion-between-trainoasis-and-muhammet).

Answer (score 1):

This is working great for me. I don't know why it doesn't take the "data-something", it seems that it doesn't like the dash between the two words. But as it works, I hope it is useful for you.

I am using [Simple HTML DOM Library](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
$my_html = '<p data="myWordToReplace"> myWordToReplace </p>';
$html = str_get_html($my_html);

foreach($html->find('p') as $p) {
    if (!empty($p->data) && ($p->data == 'myWordToReplace')) {
        $p->innertext = '<a href="#">'. $p->innertext .'</a>';
    }
}

echo $html;
```

Comment: *Lets say I want to replace all occurrences* Why do you think it is only `p`? Why do you think it is only `p data == 'myWordToReplace'`? Why do you think text contains only `myWordToReplace` ?

Comment: because is the example that @trainoasis exposed, he is looking for it. Keep it in a variable and type whatever you want, put an id on the element you want to search, or explain the question a bit better.

Comment: Thanks Sponge, also helpful

Answer (score 1):

Here is another DOM-based solution to wrap parts of text nodes into `<a>` tags (using `search` as a sample):

```
$html = "<html><body>\n<!-- This is a comment for search //-->\n<span class=\"search\">New search performed</span></body></html>";
$key = "search";
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$tt = $xpath->query('//text()');

foreach ($xpath->query('//text()') as $textNode) {
    $fragment = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
    $text = $textNode->nodeValue;

    while (($pos = stripos($text, $key)) !== false) {
      $fragment->appendChild(new DOMText(substr($text, 0, $pos)));
      $word = substr($text, $pos, strlen($key));

      $lnk = $dom->createElement('a');
      $lnk->appendChild(new DOMText($word));
      $lnk->setAttribute('href', '#');
      $fragment->appendChild($lnk);

      $text = substr($text, $pos + strlen($key));
    }
    if (!empty($text))
      $fragment->appendChild(new DOMText($text));
    $textNode->parentNode->replaceChild($fragment, $textNode);
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Here is an [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/3dMxQH)